# Зачем Apple придумала язык программирования Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple, дизайн-языка

Чем не устроил их Objective-C? Какие преимущества у Swift перед Objective-C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift — гораздо более современный язык, не отягощённый проблемами совместимости с C. Добавить фичи наподобие безопасности памяти (memory safety), обобщённых классов/методов (generics), необнуляемых ссылок (non-nullable reference types) было бы очень сложно, оставаясь в рамках Objective C. (Сравните, например, лямбды в Objective C и в Swift'е.)

Синкатсис, да и семантика C хороши для низкоуровневых языков (каким, например, C и является), но высокоуровневые фичи проще делать на другой основе.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего что пытались привлечь разработчиков с других языков программирования, таких как Java. Ну и убрали много чего, связали разработчиков по рукам, чтобы писали более одинаковый код.

Лично мне больше нравится Objective-C, так как он позволяет много чего делать, легко кастить переменные разных типов, использовать препроцессор для уменьшения объема читаемого кода и хитрых макроподстановок, рантайм, свиззлинг, в общем все то, что не любят пускать в продакшн, как якобы ненадежное или трудноподдерживаемое, хотя у меня совсем другое мнение.
Из моего опыта, те кто начинали с Java более любят Swift, кто с C/C++ – Objective-C.